# Python can't convert list into DataFrame

Tags: python, excel, list, dataframe

I try to import 2 set of data from same excel workseet, they locate in different range. 
Firstly, I have function to allow me enter range to extract data from range. Then I want to append each range data as 1 DataFrame. The code is working from extract data to append data. 
I have convert it as DataFrame but it's still in a list. When I export to excel file, it only 2 rows of data because there 2 sub-list. 
My expected output is 1 DataFrame not list, data in rows and columns.

```
#code to import workbook 
    from openpyxl import load_workbook
    from openpyxl.utils import get_column_interval
    import re

#function allow me to enter range 
    def load_workbook_range(range_string, ws):
      col_start, col_end = re.findall("[A-Z]+", range_string)

      data_rows = []
      for row in ws[range_string]:
          data_rows.append([cell.value for cell in row])

      return pd.DataFrame(data_rows, columns=get_column_interval(col_start, col_end))

# load workbook 
    wb = load_workbook(filename=b, read_only=True)
    ws = wb.active
     List = ['B24:D29','B2:D11'];

#create list for list and extra data from different range (List)
    df_list=[]
    for r in List:
      y=load_workbook_range(r,ws)
      f=pd.DataFrame(y)
      f.columns = f.iloc[0]
      g=f.drop(f.index[1])
      df_list.append(g)


    df_list

#output 

    [0  InComplete offer     NaN  Response 
     0  InComplete offer    None  Response 
     2                  1  name       Marie
     3                  2      a    13.7716
     4                  3      b    75.2104
     5                  4      c    26.8648,
     0  InComplete offer          NaN  Response 
     0  InComplete offer         None  Response 
     2                  1       name       Marie
     3                  2     invest     13.7716
     4                  3    capital     75.2104
     5                  4     income     26.8648
     6                  5    expense     83.1496
     7                  6     school     43.5749
     8                  7  transport     85.2239
     9                  8      others    82.3117]

#if I export to excel file, it is a list
    w = pd.DataFrame(df_list)
    w.to_excel (new_path, index = False, header=True)
    w

#output in excel file 

    0
    0   0 InComplete offer NaN Response 0 InCo...
    1   0 InComplete offer NaN Response 0 ...

#my expect output when export to excel file , look like below , in 3 different columns and multi rows.

    0  InComplete offer     NaN  Response 
     0  InComplete offer    None  Response 
     2                  1  name       Marie
     3                  2      a    13.7716
     4                  3      b    75.2104
     5                  4      c    26.8648,
     0  InComplete offer          NaN  Response 
     0  InComplete offer         None  Response 
     2                  1       name       Marie
     3                  2     invest     13.7716
     4                  3    capital     75.2104
     5                  4     income     26.8648
     6                  5    expense     83.1496
     7                  6     school     43.5749
     8                  7  transport     85.2239
     9                  8      others    82.3117
```

Appreciate if anyone could help & thanks. 
MC

Answer (score 0):

Try

```py
i = 0
for r in List:

    y = load_workbook_range(r,ws)
    f = pd.DataFrame(y)
    f.columns = f.iloc[0]
    g = f.drop(f.index[1])

    i += 1
    if i == 1:
       df_list = g
    else:
       df_list = df_list.append(g)
```